# Is it possible to access R's primitive "class" function via Rcpp?

Tags: r, rcpp

I am trying loop through an R list and extract the primary class (defined as the first element in the case of an S3 class) of each R object in the list.  I know it is possible to call a generic R function from Rcpp, but I would like to avoid doing that.  The reason I am pursuing this to begin with is for performance.

I saw another question here regarding access to R's primitive functions:
[use primitive functions in Rcpp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22110075/r-use-primitive-functions-like-max-sum-in-rcpp) and it looks like Rcpp's sugar expressions solved that particular issue, but it doesn't look like 'class' is available in Rcpp sugar.

I know that one can access attributes in Rcpp (which is how S3 classes are stored) and I also know that S4 objects are detectable in Rcpp, so I think there is probably a way to do this, but it would be easiest of the primitive class function were directly callable and I am just missing something.

```
library(Rcpp)

objList <- list(
    a = 10,
    b = lm(mpg~cyl, data = mtcars),
    c = glm(mpg~cyl, data = mtcars, family = gaussian)
)
##R approach
primaryClass <- function(x){
    class(x)[1]
}

vapply(objList, primaryClass, character(1))

##Rcpp skeleton approach
cppFunction('CharacterVector primaryClass(List x) {
  int nrow = x.size();
  CharacterVector out(nrow);
  for (int i = 0; i < nrow; i++) {
    out[i] = "classHere";
  }
  return out;
}')

primaryClass(objList)
```

Comment: Have you profiled your code? Are you _sure_ this is the bottleneck?

Comment: Yes - this is one of the bottle necks.  Even if it weren't, however, I'm still interested in the mechanics...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not everything that R "has" internally is available to Rcpp. There is certainly no automatic mechanism (which is why the answer on `max()` you reference shows different but equivalent `max()` functions).

But you *can* look at the `class` attribute (which covers S3):

```
R> cppFunction('std::string getClass(RObject x) { 
+      if (x.hasAttribute("class")) return x.attr("class"); else return ""; }')
R> getClass(lm.D9)         # after running `example(lm)` to get `lm.D9`
[1] "lm"
R> getClass(2.345)
[1] ""
R>
```

Similarly you can test for the other object types and add logic.